# Actionscript to Javascript

Tags: javascript, actionscript

AS3:

```
    public static function testFunction(a:Number, b:String="", c:String=""):String {
    var fmt:NumberFormatter = new NumberFormatter();
    fmt.precision = -1;
    fmt.useThousandsSeparator = false;
    var s:String = fmt.format(a);
    }
```

How to convert it to Javascript. I'm very confused and I think I need NumberFormatter in JS. Any recommend suggestions?

Comment: please provide your  logic also

Comment: Yes, what are you actually trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2):

You can set precision like this

```
 var num = 13.3714;
 var n = num.toPrecision(2);
```

for more info see http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_toprecision.asp

also http://openexchangerates.github.io/accounting.js/ and
http://numeraljs.com/